# youtube data api: recent videos are in high definition but the api returns low definition in contentDetails

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Trying to get the content details of recent uploaded videos in youtube, which are in 1080p using this request:

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=cA0FiUNr85Y&key={API_KEY}-eOB6jxA4&part=contentDetails
```

the `contentDetails` property is set to :

```
contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT2M59S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "sd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": true,
    "projection": "rectangular"
  }
```

`"definition": "sd"` should be `"definition": "hd"`

something has changed recently since old video ids seem to be working fine.